# ¿Cómo Puedo insertar dentro de un JButton un icono y texto en un salto de Linea usando NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica, icons, jbutton

Quiero agregar un icono tipo `.png` dentro de un `JButton` y con un salto de linea agregar texto, esto con la finalidad de que la GUI del proyecto se vea mejor y el usuario pueda identificar con imagen y texto la acción que se quiere realizar. Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando la **IDE NetBeans**

**He intentado lo siguiente:**

```
btnAdd_Departamentos.setText("<html><img src='../imgs/iconoAgregar.png'></html>");
```

Pero me marca error en la imagen.

Comment: ¿Has probado a utilizar HTML en el texto botón? jButton1.setText("<html>línea1<br>línea2</html>"); No hace falta ni que búsques en el código, con F2 editas el texto del botón e insertas el HTML

Comment: Precisamente eso estaba viendo, pero tengo mis dudas, por ejemplo como llamaría al icono en una de las lineas

Comment: Utilizar HTML para separar líneas es tan sencillo como escribir el código html en el texto del botón, pero no he utilizado nunca fontawesome en un proyecto java, así que ahí no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Haré pruebas a ver que tal